# The report has no tables while creating crystal report in asp .net

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net

Below is my Code foe Generating Crystal Report on Button Click:-

```
doc.Load(Server.MapPath("../Reports/BalanceSheetReport.rpt"));
Result objResult;
objBalance.updated_date = datepicker.Text;
objResult = objBalance.GetBalance();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = objResult.DataSetResult.Tables[0].DataSet;
doc.SetDataSource(ds);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = doc;
CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
```

I have Values ds , but when i write doc.setDataSource(ds) 
and 
even tried for  doc.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0])
It wil give me error like

> Report has no Tables.

Please Help me to solve this

Comment: Create SqlDataAdapter to fill in your dataSet and then bind your data set to doc

Comment: Are you sure `ds` has `DataSet` values when trying to bind on the report? Try using `doc.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);` after filling dataset from an `SqlDataAdapter`.